# How to run method on iOS when the user's device is connected to the internet?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, events, reachability

In the app which I am developing, I want to listen for an event when the user's device becomes connected to the internet. I'm thinking about the use case when if my device is not currently connected to the internet (think iPod touch, not at home where there is no wifi), and then it becomes connected to the internet (i.e., returning home). Is there an event in iOS which I can listen to in my app for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  Reachability classes - Sample is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

```
Reachability* reachability = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com"] retain];
NetworkStatus netStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
```

Comment: You need to subscribe to `kReachabilityChangedNotification` defined in that class

Answer (score 4):

You can set one with `SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback`. See a great example by Apple, called Reachability http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html